# How to prepare a table format from a JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have JSON string and it has `n` number of item, I want to convert it into a table

**Json String**

```
{"HotelSearchResult":{"ResponseStatus":1,"Error":{"ErrorCode":0,"ErrorMessage":""},"TraceId":"70e718ad-a9c2-4e82-9125-e3ee2f1573f1","CityId":"15254","CheckInDate":"2016-03-22","CheckOutDate":"2016-03-24","PreferredCurrency":"INR","NoOfRooms":1,"RoomGuests":[{"NoOfAdults":1,"NoOfChild":0,"ChildAge":[]}],"HotelResults":[{"ResultIndex":1,"HotelCode":"348043","HotelName":"Base Taupo - Hostel \/ Backpacker","HotelCategory":"","StarRating":2,"HotelDescription":"Property Location A stay at Base Taupo - Hostel \/ Backpacker places you in the heart of Taupo, walking distance from Taupo Museum and Art Gallery and Barbary.  This hostel is within Near Taupo Museum and Art Gallery  ","HotelPromotion":"","HotelPolicy":"","Price":{"CurrencyCode":"INR","RoomPrice":1837.47,"Tax":0.00,"ExtraGuestCharge":0,"ChildCharge":0,"OtherCharges":0,"Discount":0.00,"PublishedPrice":1837.47,"PublishedPriceRoundedOff":1837,"OfferedPrice":1837.47,"OfferedPriceRoundedOff":1837,"AgentCommission":0.00,"AgentMarkUp":0.00,"ServiceTax":0,"TDS":0},"HotelPicture":"http:\/\/www.travelboutiqueonline.com\/imageresource.aspx?img=ckZZ2jR\/KJFL8uCNV\/6rUdikLJoSoWwsQ4+ucla4wpAL9fwTuqkLXc3dJ9jA0ZdlXkihFvi968p+KSfi8oYVU8Tj278FBz\/1XkfoRZtaubj\/jenFXq1xBUpWskdqQlXdlSq2E+AsRgAHCH7MUGE+VOR1GoL89wEcl7bKkOpOKoV8u5\/s6kQwUbyMvkUTHXfr\/OjXIi4RNZfESY3+adSUVfiu7NVoTmH5TlFdNsylMzU=","HotelAddress":"7 Tuwharetoa Street, Taupo, , 3330, , , ","HotelContactNo":"","HotelMap":null,"Latitude":"","Longitude":"","HotelLocation":null,"SupplierPrice":null,"RoomDetails":[]},{"ResultIndex":2,"HotelCode":"444277","HotelName":"Camellia Court Family Motel","HotelCategory":"","StarRating":3,"HotelDescription":"Property Location Located in Taupo, Camellia Court Family Motel is convenient to Taupo Bungy and Taupo Museum and Art Gallery.  This motel is within close proximity of Barbary and Near Taupo Bungy  ","HotelPromotion":"","HotelPolicy":"","Price":{"CurrencyCode":"INR","RoomPrice":2721.38,"Tax":0.00,"ExtraGuestCharge":0,"ChildCharge":0,"OtherCharges":0,"Discount":0.00,"PublishedPrice":2721.38,"PublishedPriceRoundedOff":2721,"OfferedPrice":2721.38,"OfferedPriceRoundedOff":2721,"AgentCommission":0.00,"AgentMarkUp":0.00,"ServiceTax":0,"TDS":0},"HotelPicture":"http:\/\/www.travelboutiqueonline.com\/imageresource.aspx?img=ckZZ2jR\/KJFL8uCNV\/6rUdikLJoSoWwsQ4+ucla4wpAL9fwTuqkLXc3dJ9jA0ZdlXkihFvi968p+KSfi8oYVU8Tj278FBz\/1XkfoRZtaubj\/jenFXq1xBQF2KZhLrrzlriBhuyokbu67Iabfrn\/oYXyyOQZ\/9ufWgRFwVHZjjFr3Cndi8RUX2MpUZp2C+OI\/3j7hNbZEVxU3aohoWZK3Xd79WBVqb\/DrXZotWZd4wAU=","HotelAddress":"50 Tonga Street, Taupo, , 2730, , , ","HotelContactNo":"","HotelMap":null,"Latitude":"","Longitude":"","HotelLocation":null,"SupplierPrice":null,"RoomDetails":[]},}};
```

**complete data must see it**

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9VV_J4sKTataU1KdUtReFJyaUk

**Desired HTML output:**
[image]

Comment: Convert your `JSON` string into an `array` and simply loop it out

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this is that you are looking for

```
$json='{"HotelSearchResult":{"ResponseStatus":1,"Error":{"ErrorCode":...};
echo '<table><thead><tr><td>Hotel Name </td><td>Price</td><td>Action</td></tr></thead><tbody>';
$str = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($str['HotelSearchResult']['HotelResults'] as $key=> $Result) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$Result['HotelName']."</td>
        <td>".$Result['Price']['RoomPrice']."</td>
        <td><button type='button' value=".$Result['ResultIndex']." >Select</button></td>
    </tr>";
}
echo '</tbody></table>';
```

Answer (score 1):

> You should try this below is my code

```
<?php
    $json='{"HotelSearchResult":value......};
    echo "<table border='1'>";
    echo '<thead><tr><td>Hotel Name </td><td>Price</td><td>Action</td></tr></thead>';
    echo "<tbody>";
    $str = json_decode($json, true);
    foreach ($str['HotelSearchResult']['HotelResults'] as $key=> $Result) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$Result['HotelName']."</td>
            <td>".$Result['Price']['RoomPrice']."</td>
            <td><button type='button' value=".$Result['ResultIndex']." >Select</button></td>
        </tr>";
    }
    echo"</tbody>";
    echo "</table>";
```

> Below is the o/p

[image: Output screen]

Answer (score 0):

Use json_decode to get an array of PHP. Paste below code(replace with your json string ) into your localhost php file and see the result in your browser.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    $myarray = json_decode('{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}');//Replace with your json string
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($myarray);
    echo "</pre>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Answers should avoid relying on external links too much; they should be self contained, although an external link can be used as a reference. Please add some more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Use json_decode

```
mixed json_decode ( string $json 
           [, bool $assoc = false [, int $depth = 512 [, int $options = 0 ]]] )
```

Then you will have an array (with associative indices where possible) and you can run over the data with a simple foreach loop;

```
$jsonString = '{"HotelSear.....';

$data = json_decode($jsonString);

foreach($data as $k=>$v) {
    echo "key [$k] => value [$v]\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `json_decode` to decode the json data and than just loop over the structure.

```
$json = '{"HotelSearchResult...';    

echo "<table>";
$data = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($data['HotelSearchResult']['HotelResults'] as $hotelResult) {
    echo "<tr>
        <td>{$hotelResult['HotelName']}</td>
        <td>{$hotelResult['Price']['RoomPrice']}</td>
    </tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```